# Less mutation rate is performing better in bigger neural network

Tags: genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-algorithms, neuroevolution, genetic-operators, mutation-operators

I have a genetic AI neural network that evolves every generation and can add or remove neurons and change weights.

It evolves good in **first generations** with mutation rate probability of e.g. `0.005` per gene (with total 100 genes). The problem is when the neural network gets bigger (200 genes), **I must decrease mutation rate**. Otherwise it will be like a random search. (By gene I mean a connection between two neurons)

My question is how can I formulate a dynamic mutation rate?

Why does it become random search when genes are increased? Is having a probability based mutation rate wrong? For example should it be an static number instead of a probability or any other way?